# How to crop image based on binary mask

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, torch

I am using torch with some semantic segmentation algorithms to produce a binary mask of the segmented images. I would then like to crop the images based on that mask. To be clear I need to crop it on a per pixel basis. It seems like a simple problem but the only solution I can conjure up is to either invert a `draw mask` function like in the Coco API, or iterate over each pixel in the array and mask together setting the pixel to black if not needed. I feel like there is a better way of doing this. Libraries in Lua, Python, Go, or C++ will work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: use findContours or extract all mask points (manually) and use the minBoundingRect function. Afterwards use subimage to get the cropped image.

Answer (score 7):

I've implemented this in Python, assuming that you have your input image and mask available as Mat Objects.
Given that src1 is your image and src1_mask is your binary mask:

```
src1_mask=cv2.cvtColor(src1_mask,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)#change mask to a 3 channel image 
mask_out=cv2.subtract(src1_mask,src1)
mask_out=cv2.subtract(src1_mask,mask_out)
```

Now mask_out contains the part of the image src1 located inside the binary mask you defined.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution relying only on numpy:

```
def get_segment_crop(img,tol=0, mask=None):
    if mask is None:
        mask = img > tol
    return img[np.ix_(mask.any(1), mask.any(0))]
```

now execute `get_segment_crop(rgb, mask=segment_mask)` where `rgb` is an ndarray of shape (w,h,c) and `segment_mask` is a boolean ndarray (i.e. containing True/False entries) of shape (w,h), given that w=width, h=height.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else running into this. I found good luck with converting the torch binary mask tensor into type `Double`, and then simply multiplying it using torch's `cmul` function against each of the RGB channels. Basically, because the binary mask has a `1` in place of a segmented pixel, then the value will just remain. Whereas if it is outside the segmentation it has a `0` which when multiplied across the channels produces black. Saransh's answer is also good, and works well for open cv.

Answer (score 2):

Use OpenCV .copyTo with the mask option

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-copyto

Answer (score 0):

**mask contain patches in white colour on black background**

```
src1=cv2.imread('image.png',0)
mask=cv2.imread('label.png',0)
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(mask, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
src1 [thresh1==0] = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `boundingRect` function from opencv to retrieve the rectangle of interest, and you can crop the image to that rectangle. A python implementation would look something like this:

```python
import numpy as np
import cv2

mask = np.zeros([600,600], dtype=np.uint8)
mask[200:500,200:500] = 255                 # set some values to 255 to represent an actual mask
rect = cv2.boundingRect(mask)               # function that computes the rectangle of interest
print(rect)

img = np.ones([600,600, 3], dtype=np.uint8) # arbitrary image
cropped_img = img[rect[1]:(rect[1]+rect[3]), rect[0]:(rect[0]+rect[2])] # crop the image to the desired rectangle
```

substitute `mask` an `img` with your own

Comment: Unfortunately I need a per-pixel crop solution