# Cropping image from a binary mask

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to use DeepLab v3 to detect object and mask where the actual object is.
DeepLab model produces a `resized_im`(3D) and a mask `seg_map` (2D) of 0 and non-zero values, 0 means it's the background.

Currently, it is only possible to plot an image with an overlay mask on the object. I want to crop the object out of the `resized_im` with transparent background. Is there any advice for the work?

You can play around with the notebook here:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/138dTpcYfne40hqrb13n_36okSGYhrJnz?usp=sharing&hl=en#scrollTo=p47cYGGOQE1W&forceEdit=true&sandboxMode=true

I also tried here: [How to crop image based on binary mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824245/how-to-crop-image-based-on-binary-mask) but none seems to work on my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to convert your segmentation mask to boolean numpy array, then multiply image by it. Don't forget that your image has 3 channels while mask has only 1. It may look something like that:

```
# seg_map - segmentation mask from network, resized_im - your input image
mask = np.greater(seg_map, 0) # get only non-zero positive pixels/labels
mask = np.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1) # (H, W) -> (H, W, 1)
mask = np.concatenate((mask, mask, mask), axis=-1) # (H, W, 1) -> (H, W, 3), (don't like it, so if you know how to do it better, please let me know)
crops = resized_im * mask # apply mask on image
```

You can use different logical numpy function if you want to choose certain labels, for example:

```
mask = np.equal(seg_map, 5) # to get only objects with label 5
```

Comment: it works! But is ```crops``` has a black background, or is it transparent?

Comment: Glad it helped! Result has a black background, because this is a simple 3-channel RGB image. To set transparent areas you need to add additional channel. Why do you need transparent background? If you want to save it to a file (I guess, .png), then you can do something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290096/python-opencv-add-alpha-channel-to-rgb-image

Comment: And if you want to use it further in python, for example, add it to another image, so black background is perfectly fine for it. In this case, if I were you, I would used opencv (https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_image_arithmetics/py_image_arithmetics.html). And also I recommend you to read about image representation (for example, this: https://techtutorialsx.com/2020/03/02/python-opencv-splitting-image-channels/)